# Difficulties with using Flashlight/Torch in Xamarin.Forms (Xamarin.Android) Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera2

### Problem

Errors and Exceptions when trying to Turn on flashlight/Torch on an Android device using Xamarin.Forms (Xamarin.Android project) app.

**Please see the below code' comments for the errors and exceptions mentioned:**

```
        // Get CameraService - This works fine and gets the CameraService
        CameraManager CamMgr = (CameraManager) Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService); 


        // Get Cameras - This Returns 0 strings, eg. NULL, it should return id 0 and 1 for respectively back and front camera

        string[] CamIdList = CamMgr.GetCameraIdList();


        // Turn ON Camera Torch(Flashlight) on camera id 0 - This results in the exception: Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setTorchMode' signature='(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V' in class Landroid/hardware/camera2/CameraManager;

        CamMgr.SetTorchMode("0", true);


        // Turn ON Camera Torch(Flashlight) on camera id 1 - This results in the exception: Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setTorchMode' signature='(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V' in class Landroid/hardware/camera2/CameraManager;
        CamMgr.SetTorchMode("1", true);
```

**Android Manifest permissions:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
    <application android:label="Lommelygte.Android"></application>
</manifest>
```

### Platform and Developing environment

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 15.0.0-RTW+26228.4 version  as IDE.

I am using Android namespace (Xamarin assembly): Android.Hardware.Camera2 to use Flashlight functionality.

My Xamarin.Forms Project is using PCL (Portable Class Library) for sharing code.

I am not using Xamarin.Forms Pre release nuget packages or libraries.

I am using Xamarin.Forms (Xamarin.Android project)

I am using Device Samsung Galaxy Note 2 LTE (GT7105) - Android 4.4.2 (Kitkat) - API Level 19 (has Camera flash functionality) to debug application on.

### **What I have tried to resolve the problem:**

- Installed Android API 19 SDK
- Cleaned Project, Then cleaned Solution, then Rebuild Solution
- Checked for new Xamarin.Forms stable release
- Tried using decrecated API 21 namespace + class instead for flash: Android.Hardware.Camera.Open();
- Researched Xamarin Documentation
- Researhed Stackoverflow posts
- Researched various blogs and other places
- Changed Target Framework to the exact API 19 that my phone supports: 4.4.2 (kitkat)
- Researched implementations in Java, to get an overview of how it natively is done.
- Looked at the definition of the Android.Hardware.Camera2 namespace and verified that the SetTorchMode method exists there, as displayed here (I am sorry for the majority of the code not being presented correctly in a codeblock, having some trouble with that):

  Assembly Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065

  using System;
  using Android.OS;
  using Android.Runtime;
  using Java.Interop;
  using Java.Lang;

  namespace Android.Hardware.Camera2
  {
      [Register("android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager", DoNotGenerateAcw = true, ApiSince = 21)]
      public sealed class CameraManager : Java.Lang.Object
      {
          public override JniPeerMembers JniPeerMembers { get; }
          protected override IntPtr ThresholdClass { get; }
          protected override Type ThresholdType { get; }

  ```
      [Register("getCameraCharacteristics", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics;", "")]
      public CameraCharacteristics GetCameraCharacteristics(string cameraId);
      [Register("getCameraIdList", "()[Ljava/lang/String;", "")]
      public string[] GetCameraIdList();
      [Register("registerAvailabilityCallback", "(Landroid/hardware/camera2/CameraManager$AvailabilityCallback;Landroid/os/Handler;)V", "")]
      public void RegisterAvailabilityCallback(AvailabilityCallback callback, Handler handler);

      [Register("setTorchMode", "(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V", "", ApiSince = 23)]
      public void SetTorchMode(string cameraId, bool enabled);
  ```

### **What I have not done yet**

....

### Hypothesis

I am suspecting that the Xamarin assembly that handles the Android.Hardware.Camera2 does not interface correctly with all the methods of the java implementation of the namespace, in particular the Class: Camera, Method: setTorchMode.

However I cant find a new stable Xamarin version that might solve the problem.

I also suspect that because the definition says API since 23 that the code won't work at runtime on my device, because it does not support API 23 and the definition seems to require it, so how do I get around this?
This is the exact register for the definition of said method:
 [Register("setTorchMode", "(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V", "", **ApiSince = 23**)]

---

How can I solve this?

Do you need more information to help me figure out the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your phone is **`API 19`**, `CameraManager` was added in **`API 21`** and `CameraManager.setTorchMode` was added in **`API 23`**. Thus, those methods can *not* be called when running on that phone.

You can perform runtime checks to determine which API levels to use:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt <= BuildVersionCodes.KitkatWatch)
{
    if (PackageManager.HasSystemFeature("FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH"))
    {
        camera = Camera.Open(); // `Camera camera` variable is held as the class level
        var camParameters = camera.GetParameters();
        camParameters.FlashMode = "FLASH_MODE_TORCH";
        camera.SetParameters(camParameters);
        camera.StartPreview(); // Turn on

        //When done with flashlight:
        //camera.StopPreview(); // Turn off
        //camera.Dispose();
    }
    else
        Log.Debug("SO", "Phone does not contain a flash....");
}
else
{
    // Use API 21+ methods... 
}
```

**Note:** ***Many*** phones that have a "torch" mode but are older than `API 21`, require a `SurfaceView` to be used so the camera will function properly and thus allow the flash to function. Add a `SurfaceView` to your UI, get a `SurfaceHolder` from it and attach the camera to it (`camera.SetPreviewDisplay`)

Comment: Wow, that was a fast response :)
Awesome, figured it might be that the API of the class was too high for my phone. So I tried implementing the Android.Hardware.Camera code you suggest, but didnt quite get it to work. I will see if I can get it to work with your solution and report back. Thanks.
Is there anyway not to have to implement a surfaceview, since I dont want to use the camera, just the flash function?
Just an additional question regarding the structure of this post, do you think this post' structure is good in terms of the structure of other questions on stackoverflow?

Comment: The android.hardware.camera API requires that you set a preview target; while some devices let you avoid doing that, it will not work on many.  If you don't care about preview output, the simplest option is to create a dummy SurfaceTexture object: private SurfaceTexture mSurface; ... mSurface = new SurfaceTexture(/*any positive number here*/ 5); camera.setPreviewTexture(mSurface); camera.startPreview();

Comment: I havent yet tested and verified the solution, but I have implemented the code and it runs without problems :)
However the flashlight did unfortunately not turn on, so either I have made a mess up in the order of operations. 
I havent been able to debug this issue yet, because the Xamarin project decided once again to be annoying and waste my time, by removing the paths to the Xamarin.Android.XXX referenced .Dll' and refusing to accept them even after reinstalling the Xamarin.Forms nuget packages and Manually referencing the troublesome references to their respective Dll.